# Why I get type mismatch in scala Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

First, I read a text file and turn it into RDD[(String,(String,Float))]:

```
val data = sc.textFile(dataInputPath);
val dataRDD:RDD[(String,(String,Float))] = data.map{f=> {
      val temp=f.split("//x01");
      (temp(0),(temp(1),temp(2).toInt ) );
      }
    } ;
```

Then, I run following code to turn my data into Rating type

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating
val imeiMap = dataRDD.reduceByKey((s1,s2)=>s1).collect().zipWithIndex.toMap;
val docidMap = dataRDD.map( f=>(f._2._1,1)).reduceByKey((s1,s2)=>s1).collect().zipWithIndex.toMap;
val ratings = dataRDD.map{case (imei, (doc_id,rating))=> Rating(imeiMap(imei),docidMap(doc_id),rating)};
```

But I got an error:

```
Error:(32, 77) type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: (String, (String, Float))
    val ratings = dataRDD.map{case (imei, (doc_id,rating))=> Rating(imeiMap(imei),docidMap(doc_id),rating)};
```

Why this happen? I think that the `string` have already changed to `(String, (String, Float))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key of docidMap is not a String, is a Tuple (String, Int)

This is because you have the zipWithIndex before the `.toMap` method:

With this rdd as input for a quick test:

```
(String1,( String2,32.0))
(String1,( String2,35.0))



scala> val docidMap = dataRDD.map( f=>(f._2._1,1)).reduceByKey((s1,s2)=>s1).collect().zipWithIndex.toMap;
docidMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(String, Int),Int] = Map((" String2",1) -> 0)


val docidMap = dataRDD.map( f=>(f._2._1,1)).reduceByKey((s1,s2)=>s1).collect().toMap;
docidMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(" String2" -> 1)
```

The same will happen with your `imeiMap`, it seems that you just need to remove the `zipWithIndex` from there too

```
val imeiMap = dataRDD.reduceByKey((s1,s2)=>s1).collect.toMap
```

Answer (score 2):

it is not about your `dataRDD`, it is about `imeiMap`:

```
imeiMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(String, (String, Float)),Int]
```